Parse simple XML string (SOAP) to PHP Object
I have below XML string which i got in the response of an SOAP API, which i want to convert as Object or  Array to use, so i tried both ways, DOM and simplexml_load_string
but it shows empty!
Here is XML
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soap:Body xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"><OTA_AirAvailRS EchoToken="1717127940" PrimaryLangID="en-us" RetransmissionIndicator="false" SequenceNmbr="1" TransactionIdentifier="TID$171712797619728342-19C.de1191" Version="2006.01"><Success /><Warnings /><OriginDestinationInformation SameAirportInd="false"><DepartureDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-05T07:00:00</DepartureDateTime><ArrivalDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-05T08:55:00</ArrivalDateTime><OriginLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="KHI" MultiAirportCityInd="false">Karachi</OriginLocation><DestinationLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="ISB" MultiAirportCityInd="false">Islamabad</DestinationLocation><OriginDestinationOptions><OriginDestinationOption><FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2024-06-05T08:55:00" DepartureDateTime="2024-06-05T07:00:00" FlightNumber="9P670" JourneyDuration="PT1H55M0.000S" RPH="9P$KHI/ISB$12249$20240605070000$20240605085500" SmokingAllowed="false" returnFlag="false"><DepartureAirport LocationCode="KHI" Terminal="" /><ArrivalAirport LocationCode="ISB" Terminal="" /></FlightSegment></OriginDestinationOption></OriginDestinationOptions></OriginDestinationInformation><OriginDestinationInformation SameAirportInd="false"><DepartureDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-05T15:25:00</DepartureDateTime><ArrivalDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-05T17:20:00</ArrivalDateTime><OriginLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="KHI" MultiAirportCityInd="false">Karachi</OriginLocation><DestinationLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="ISB" MultiAirportCityInd="false">Islamabad</DestinationLocation><OriginDestinationOptions><OriginDestinationOption><FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2024-06-05T17:20:00" DepartureDateTime="2024-06-05T15:25:00" FlightNumber="9P672" JourneyDuration="PT1H55M0.000S" RPH="9P$KHI/ISB$12459$20240605152500$20240605172000" SmokingAllowed="false" returnFlag="false"><DepartureAirport LocationCode="KHI" Terminal="" /><ArrivalAirport LocationCode="ISB" Terminal="" /></FlightSegment></OriginDestinationOption></OriginDestinationOptions></OriginDestinationInformation><OriginDestinationInformation SameAirportInd="false"><DepartureDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-05T18:20:00</DepartureDateTime><ArrivalDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-05T20:15:00</ArrivalDateTime><OriginLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="KHI" MultiAirportCityInd="false">Karachi</OriginLocation><DestinationLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="ISB" MultiAirportCityInd="false">Islamabad</DestinationLocation><OriginDestinationOptions><OriginDestinationOption><FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2024-06-05T20:15:00" DepartureDateTime="2024-06-05T18:20:00" FlightNumber="9P674" JourneyDuration="PT1H55M0.000S" RPH="9P$KHI/ISB$9939$20240605182000$20240605201500" SmokingAllowed="false" returnFlag="false"><DepartureAirport LocationCode="KHI" Terminal="" /><ArrivalAirport LocationCode="ISB" Terminal="" /></FlightSegment></OriginDestinationOption></OriginDestinationOptions></OriginDestinationInformation><OriginDestinationInformation SameAirportInd="false"><DepartureDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-05T09:00:00</DepartureDateTime><ArrivalDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-05T13:05:00</ArrivalDateTime><OriginLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="SHJ" MultiAirportCityInd="false">SHARJAH INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT</OriginLocation><DestinationLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="ISB" MultiAirportCityInd="false">Islamabad</DestinationLocation><OriginDestinationOptions><OriginDestinationOption><FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2024-06-05T13:05:00" DepartureDateTime="2024-06-05T09:00:00" FlightNumber="9P741" JourneyDuration="PT3H5M0.000S" RPH="9P$SHJ/ISB$9302$20240605090000$20240605130500" SmokingAllowed="false" returnFlag="false"><DepartureAirport LocationCode="SHJ" Terminal="" /><ArrivalAirport LocationCode="ISB" Terminal="" /></FlightSegment></OriginDestinationOption></OriginDestinationOptions></OriginDestinationInformation><OriginDestinationInformation SameAirportInd="false"><DepartureDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-05T23:30:00</DepartureDateTime><ArrivalDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-06T03:35:00</ArrivalDateTime><OriginLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="SHJ" MultiAirportCityInd="false">SHARJAH INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT</OriginLocation><DestinationLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="ISB" MultiAirportCityInd="false">Islamabad</DestinationLocation><OriginDestinationOptions><OriginDestinationOption><FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2024-06-06T03:35:00" DepartureDateTime="2024-06-05T23:30:00" FlightNumber="9P743" JourneyDuration="PT3H5M0.000S" RPH="9P$SHJ/ISB$9722$20240605233000$20240606033500" SmokingAllowed="false" returnFlag="false"><DepartureAirport LocationCode="SHJ" Terminal="" /><ArrivalAirport LocationCode="ISB" Terminal="" /></FlightSegment></OriginDestinationOption></OriginDestinationOptions></OriginDestinationInformation><OriginDestinationInformation SameAirportInd="false"><DepartureDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-06T09:00:00</DepartureDateTime><ArrivalDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-06T13:05:00</ArrivalDateTime><OriginLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="SHJ" MultiAirportCityInd="false">SHARJAH INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT</OriginLocation><DestinationLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="ISB" MultiAirportCityInd="false">Islamabad</DestinationLocation><OriginDestinationOptions><OriginDestinationOption><FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2024-06-06T13:05:00" DepartureDateTime="2024-06-06T09:00:00" FlightNumber="9P741" JourneyDuration="PT3H5M0.000S" RPH="9P$SHJ/ISB$9303$20240606090000$20240606130500" SmokingAllowed="false" returnFlag="false"><DepartureAirport LocationCode="SHJ" Terminal="" /><ArrivalAirport LocationCode="ISB" Terminal="" /></FlightSegment></OriginDestinationOption></OriginDestinationOptions></OriginDestinationInformation><AAAirAvailRSExt><PricedItineraries><PricedItinerary SequenceNumber="1"><AirItinerary><OriginDestinationOptions><OriginDestinationOption><FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2024-06-05T17:20:00" DepartureDateTime="2024-06-05T15:25:00" FlightNumber="9P672" RPH="9P$KHI/ISB$12459$20240605152500$20240605172000" returnFlag="false"><DepartureAirport LocationCode="KHI" Terminal="" /><ArrivalAirport LocationCode="ISB" Terminal="" /></FlightSegment></OriginDestinationOption><AABundledServiceExt applicableOnd="KHI/ISB" applicableOndSequence="0"><bundledService><bunldedServiceId>147</bunldedServiceId><bundledServiceName>Value</bundledServiceName><perPaxBundledFee>1800.00</perPaxBundledFee><bookingClasses>Y5</bookingClasses><description>10 Kg Carry-on Baggage
23 Kg Checked Baggage
Sandwich with Soft Drinks
Free Seat (row 8 onwards)
Free Modification (One Up to 24h)</description><includedServies>BAGGAGE</includedServies><includedServies>SEAT_MAP</includedServies><includedServies>MEAL</includedServies><includedServies>FLEXI_CHARGES</includedServies></bundledService><bundledService><bunldedServiceId>46</bunldedServiceId><bundledServiceName>Ultimate</bundledServiceName><perPaxBundledFee>2900.00</perPaxBundledFee><bookingClasses>Y5</bookingClasses><description>10 Kg Carry-on Baggage
46 Kg Checked Baggage
Premium Meal, Desert and Salad
Any Seat – Including Front Row
2 Free Modification (Up to 6h)
1 Free Cancellation (Up to 6h)
Priority Check-in
50% Cash Refund* (Up to 24h)</description><includedServies>BAGGAGE</includedServies><includedServies>SEAT_MAP</includedServies><includedServies>MEAL</includedServies><includedServies>AIRPORT_SERVICE</includedServies><includedServies>FLEXI_CHARGES</includedServies></bundledService></AABundledServiceExt></OriginDestinationOptions></AirItinerary><AirItineraryPricingInfo PricingSource="Published"><ItinTotalFare NegotiatedFare="false"><BaseFare Amount="17855.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" /><EquiBaseFare Amount="17855.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" /><TotalFare Amount="20000.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" /><TotalEquivFare Amount="20000.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" /><TotalFareWithCCFee Amount="20000.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" /><TotalEquivFareWithCCFee Amount="20000.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" /></ItinTotalFare><PTC_FareBreakdowns><PTC_FareBreakdown PricingSource="Published"><PassengerTypeQuantity Age="0" Code="ADT" Quantity="1" /><FareBasisCodes><FareBasisCode>P</FareBasisCode></FareBasisCodes><PassengerFare NegotiatedFare="false"><BaseFare Amount="17855.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" /><EquiBaseFare Amount="17855.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" /><Taxes><Tax Amount="25.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" TaxCode="N9DOM" TaxName="Pakistan DOM Stamp Duty (N9)" /><Tax Amount="500.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" TaxCode="SPDOM" TaxName="Pakistan DOM Embarkation Fee (SP)" /><Tax Amount="100.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" TaxCode="XZDOM" TaxName="Pakistan DOM Security Charge (XZ)" /><Tax Amount="20.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" TaxCode="YIDOM" TaxName="Pakistan DOM Government Airport Tax (YI)" /><Tax Amount="1500.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" TaxCode="PKDOM" TaxName="Pakistan DOM Excise Duty (PK)" /></Taxes><Fees /><TotalFare Amount="20000.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" /></PassengerFare><TravelerRefNumber RPH="A1" /></PTC_FareBreakdown></PTC_FareBreakdowns></AirItineraryPricingInfo></PricedItinerary></PricedItineraries></AAAirAvailRSExt><Errors /></OTA_AirAvailRS></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

I tried simplexml_load_string first like below but it only shows empty
$parser = simplexml_load_string($txt, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);  
$responseFormat =  $parser->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body->children()->OTA_AirAvailRS; 
        
var_dump($responseFormat);

Then i tried the DOM object aswell as below
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML ($txt);
            
$xml->xinclude();
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($xml);
var_dump($xml);

Tried following aswell, as saw in other Stack Over flow question, But still No Good Luck.
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadXML($result);

$parser=$domDocument->getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05", "OTA_AirAvailRS");
var_dump($parser);

without replacing NS2 original XML comes as below, but i replaced NS1 by using str_replace
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body xmlns:ns1="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
        <ns1:OTA_AirAvailRS EchoToken="11868765275150-1300255654" PrimaryLangID="en-us" RetransmissionIndicator="false" SequenceNmbr="1" TransactionIdentifier="TID$171712020644794-95.de1191" Version="2006.01">
            <ns1:Success />
            <ns1:Warnings />
            <ns1:OriginDestinationInformation SameAirportInd="false">
                <ns1:DepartureDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-15T07:00:00</ns1:DepartureDateTime>
                <ns1:ArrivalDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-15T08:55:00</ns1:ArrivalDateTime>
                <ns1:OriginLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="KHI" MultiAirportCityInd="false">Karachi</ns1:OriginLocation>
                <ns1:DestinationLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="ISB" MultiAirportCityInd="false">Islamabad</ns1:DestinationLocation>
                <ns1:OriginDestinationOptions>
                    <ns1:OriginDestinationOption>
                        <ns1:FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2024-06-15T08:55:00" DepartureDateTime="2024-06-15T07:00:00" FlightNumber="9P670" JourneyDuration="PT1H55M0.000S" RPH="9P$KHI/ISB$12259$20240615070000$20240615085500" SmokingAllowed="false" returnFlag="false">
                            <ns1:DepartureAirport LocationCode="KHI" Terminal="" />
                            <ns1:ArrivalAirport LocationCode="ISB" Terminal="" />
                        </ns1:FlightSegment>
                    </ns1:OriginDestinationOption>
                </ns1:OriginDestinationOptions>
            </ns1:OriginDestinationInformation>
            <ns1:OriginDestinationInformation SameAirportInd="false">
                <ns1:DepartureDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-15T15:25:00</ns1:DepartureDateTime>
                <ns1:ArrivalDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-15T17:20:00</ns1:ArrivalDateTime>
                <ns1:OriginLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="KHI" MultiAirportCityInd="false">Karachi</ns1:OriginLocation>
                <ns1:DestinationLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="ISB" MultiAirportCityInd="false">Islamabad</ns1:DestinationLocation>
                <ns1:OriginDestinationOptions>
                    <ns1:OriginDestinationOption>
                        <ns1:FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2024-06-15T17:20:00" DepartureDateTime="2024-06-15T15:25:00" FlightNumber="9P672" JourneyDuration="PT1H55M0.000S" RPH="9P$KHI/ISB$12469$20240615152500$20240615172000" SmokingAllowed="false" returnFlag="false">
                            <ns1:DepartureAirport LocationCode="KHI" Terminal="" />
                            <ns1:ArrivalAirport LocationCode="ISB" Terminal="" />
                        </ns1:FlightSegment>
                    </ns1:OriginDestinationOption>
                </ns1:OriginDestinationOptions>
            </ns1:OriginDestinationInformation>
            <ns1:OriginDestinationInformation SameAirportInd="false">
                <ns1:DepartureDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-15T18:20:00</ns1:DepartureDateTime>
                <ns1:ArrivalDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-15T20:15:00</ns1:ArrivalDateTime>
                <ns1:OriginLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="KHI" MultiAirportCityInd="false">Karachi</ns1:OriginLocation>
                <ns1:DestinationLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="ISB" MultiAirportCityInd="false">Islamabad</ns1:DestinationLocation>
                <ns1:OriginDestinationOptions>
                    <ns1:OriginDestinationOption>
                        <ns1:FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2024-06-15T20:15:00" DepartureDateTime="2024-06-15T18:20:00" FlightNumber="9P674" JourneyDuration="PT1H55M0.000S" RPH="9P$KHI/ISB$9949$20240615182000$20240615201500" SmokingAllowed="false" returnFlag="false">
                            <ns1:DepartureAirport LocationCode="KHI" Terminal="" />
                            <ns1:ArrivalAirport LocationCode="ISB" Terminal="" />
                        </ns1:FlightSegment>
                    </ns1:OriginDestinationOption>
                </ns1:OriginDestinationOptions>
            </ns1:OriginDestinationInformation>
            <ns1:OriginDestinationInformation SameAirportInd="false">
                <ns1:DepartureDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-15T09:00:00</ns1:DepartureDateTime>
                <ns1:ArrivalDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-15T13:05:00</ns1:ArrivalDateTime>
                <ns1:OriginLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="SHJ" MultiAirportCityInd="false">SHARJAH INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT</ns1:OriginLocation>
                <ns1:DestinationLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="ISB" MultiAirportCityInd="false">Islamabad</ns1:DestinationLocation>
                <ns1:OriginDestinationOptions>
                    <ns1:OriginDestinationOption>
                        <ns1:FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2024-06-15T13:05:00" DepartureDateTime="2024-06-15T09:00:00" FlightNumber="9P741" JourneyDuration="PT3H5M0.000S" RPH="9P$SHJ/ISB$9312$20240615090000$20240615130500" SmokingAllowed="false" returnFlag="false">
                            <ns1:DepartureAirport LocationCode="SHJ" Terminal="" />
                            <ns1:ArrivalAirport LocationCode="ISB" Terminal="" />
                        </ns1:FlightSegment>
                    </ns1:OriginDestinationOption>
                </ns1:OriginDestinationOptions>
            </ns1:OriginDestinationInformation>
            <ns1:OriginDestinationInformation SameAirportInd="false">
                <ns1:DepartureDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-15T23:30:00</ns1:DepartureDateTime>
                <ns1:ArrivalDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-16T03:35:00</ns1:ArrivalDateTime>
                <ns1:OriginLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="SHJ" MultiAirportCityInd="false">SHARJAH INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT</ns1:OriginLocation>
                <ns1:DestinationLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="ISB" MultiAirportCityInd="false">Islamabad</ns1:DestinationLocation>
                <ns1:OriginDestinationOptions>
                    <ns1:OriginDestinationOption>
                        <ns1:FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2024-06-16T03:35:00" DepartureDateTime="2024-06-15T23:30:00" FlightNumber="9P743" JourneyDuration="PT3H5M0.000S" RPH="9P$SHJ/ISB$9732$20240615233000$20240616033500" SmokingAllowed="false" returnFlag="false">
                            <ns1:DepartureAirport LocationCode="SHJ" Terminal="" />
                            <ns1:ArrivalAirport LocationCode="ISB" Terminal="" />
                        </ns1:FlightSegment>
                    </ns1:OriginDestinationOption>
                </ns1:OriginDestinationOptions>
            </ns1:OriginDestinationInformation>
            <ns1:OriginDestinationInformation SameAirportInd="false">
                <ns1:DepartureDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-16T09:00:00</ns1:DepartureDateTime>
                <ns1:ArrivalDateTime CrossDateAllowedIndicator="false">2024-06-16T13:05:00</ns1:ArrivalDateTime>
                <ns1:OriginLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="SHJ" MultiAirportCityInd="false">SHARJAH INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT</ns1:OriginLocation>
                <ns1:DestinationLocation AlternateLocationInd="false" LocationCode="ISB" MultiAirportCityInd="false">Islamabad</ns1:DestinationLocation>
                <ns1:OriginDestinationOptions>
                    <ns1:OriginDestinationOption>
                        <ns1:FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2024-06-16T13:05:00" DepartureDateTime="2024-06-16T09:00:00" FlightNumber="9P741" JourneyDuration="PT3H5M0.000S" RPH="9P$SHJ/ISB$9313$20240616090000$20240616130500" SmokingAllowed="false" returnFlag="false">
                            <ns1:DepartureAirport LocationCode="SHJ" Terminal="" />
                            <ns1:ArrivalAirport LocationCode="ISB" Terminal="" />
                        </ns1:FlightSegment>
                    </ns1:OriginDestinationOption>
                </ns1:OriginDestinationOptions>
            </ns1:OriginDestinationInformation>
            <ns1:AAAirAvailRSExt>
                <ns1:PricedItineraries>
                    <ns1:PricedItinerary SequenceNumber="1">
                        <ns1:AirItinerary>
                            <ns1:OriginDestinationOptions>
                                <ns1:OriginDestinationOption>
                                    <ns1:FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2024-06-15T20:15:00" DepartureDateTime="2024-06-15T18:20:00" FlightNumber="9P674" RPH="9P$KHI/ISB$9949$20240615182000$20240615201500" returnFlag="false">
                                        <ns1:DepartureAirport LocationCode="KHI" Terminal="" />
                                        <ns1:ArrivalAirport LocationCode="ISB" Terminal="" />
                                    </ns1:FlightSegment>
                                </ns1:OriginDestinationOption>
                                <ns1:AABundledServiceExt applicableOnd="KHI/ISB" applicableOndSequence="0">
                                    <ns1:bundledService>
                                        <ns1:bunldedServiceId>147</ns1:bunldedServiceId>
                                        <ns1:bundledServiceName>Value</ns1:bundledServiceName>
                                        <ns1:perPaxBundledFee>1800.00</ns1:perPaxBundledFee>
                                        <ns1:bookingClasses>Y9</ns1:bookingClasses>
                                        <ns1:description>10 Kg Carry-on Baggage
23 Kg Checked Baggage
Sandwich with Soft Drinks
Free Seat (row 8 onwards)
Free Modification (One Up to 24h)</ns1:description>
                                        <ns1:includedServies>BAGGAGE</ns1:includedServies>
                                        <ns1:includedServies>SEAT_MAP</ns1:includedServies>
                                        <ns1:includedServies>MEAL</ns1:includedServies>
                                        <ns1:includedServies>FLEXI_CHARGES</ns1:includedServies>
                                    </ns1:bundledService>
                                    <ns1:bundledService>
                                        <ns1:bunldedServiceId>46</ns1:bunldedServiceId>
                                        <ns1:bundledServiceName>Ultimate</ns1:bundledServiceName>
                                        <ns1:perPaxBundledFee>2900.00</ns1:perPaxBundledFee>
                                        <ns1:bookingClasses>Y9</ns1:bookingClasses>
                                        <ns1:description>10 Kg Carry-on Baggage
46 Kg Checked Baggage
Premium Meal, Desert and Salad
Any Seat – Including Front Row
2 Free Modification (Up to 6h)
1 Free Cancellation (Up to 6h)
Priority Check-in
50% Cash Refund* (Up to 24h)</ns1:description>
                                        <ns1:includedServies>BAGGAGE</ns1:includedServies>
                                        <ns1:includedServies>SEAT_MAP</ns1:includedServies>
                                        <ns1:includedServies>MEAL</ns1:includedServies>
                                        <ns1:includedServies>AIRPORT_SERVICE</ns1:includedServies>
                                        <ns1:includedServies>FLEXI_CHARGES</ns1:includedServies>
                                    </ns1:bundledService>
                                </ns1:AABundledServiceExt>
                            </ns1:OriginDestinationOptions>
                        </ns1:AirItinerary>
                        <ns1:AirItineraryPricingInfo PricingSource="Published">
                            <ns1:ItinTotalFare NegotiatedFare="false">
                                <ns1:BaseFare Amount="25355.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" />
                                <ns1:EquiBaseFare Amount="25355.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" />
                                <ns1:TotalFare Amount="27780.73" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" />
                                <ns1:TotalEquivFare Amount="27780.73" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" />
                                <ns1:TotalFareWithCCFee Amount="27780.73" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" />
                                <ns1:TotalEquivFareWithCCFee Amount="27780.73" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" />
                            </ns1:ItinTotalFare>
                            <ns1:PTC_FareBreakdowns>
                                <ns1:PTC_FareBreakdown PricingSource="Published">
                                    <ns1:PassengerTypeQuantity Age="0" Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />
                                    <ns1:FareBasisCodes>
                                        <ns1:FareBasisCode>P</ns1:FareBasisCode>
                                    </ns1:FareBasisCodes>
                                    <ns1:PassengerFare NegotiatedFare="false">
                                        <ns1:BaseFare Amount="25355.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" />
                                        <ns1:EquiBaseFare Amount="25355.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" />
                                        <ns1:Taxes>
                                            <ns1:Tax Amount="25.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" TaxCode="N9DOM" TaxName="Pakistan DOM Stamp Duty (N9)" />
                                            <ns1:Tax Amount="500.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" TaxCode="SPDOM" TaxName="Pakistan DOM Embarkation Fee (SP)" />
                                            <ns1:Tax Amount="100.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" TaxCode="XZDOM" TaxName="Pakistan DOM Security Charge (XZ)" />
                                            <ns1:Tax Amount="20.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" TaxCode="YIDOM" TaxName="Pakistan DOM Government Airport Tax (YI)" />
                                            <ns1:Tax Amount="1500.00" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" TaxCode="PKDOM" TaxName="Pakistan DOM Excise Duty (PK)" />
                                        </ns1:Taxes>
                                        <ns1:Fees>
                                            <ns1:Fee Amount="280.73" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" FeeCode="9PWKDSUR/Weekend SUR 9P DOM" />
                                        </ns1:Fees>
                                        <ns1:TotalFare Amount="27780.73" CurrencyCode="PKR" DecimalPlaces="2" />
                                    </ns1:PassengerFare>
                                    <ns1:TravelerRefNumber RPH="A1" />
                                </ns1:PTC_FareBreakdown>
                            </ns1:PTC_FareBreakdowns>
                        </ns1:AirItineraryPricingInfo>
                    </ns1:PricedItinerary>
                </ns1:PricedItineraries>
            </ns1:AAAirAvailRSExt>
            <ns1:Errors />
        </ns1:OTA_AirAvailRS>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Please if anyone can guide what i am doing wrong?

You are just missing the namespace URI in you second 'children()' call. I usually put the namespaces into an array to make my source more readable. $xmlns = ['SOAP' => '...', 'OT' => '...']; ... $envelope->children($xmlns['SOAP'])->Body->children($xmlns['OT'])->OTA_AirAvailRS

I have achieved this finally by using below code by modifying as got a clue at Parse SOAP XML feed in PHP
I have noticed that SOAP & SOAP-ENV must not be in tags
        $result = str_replace("ns1:","",$result);
    $result = str_replace(":ns1","",$result);
    $result = str_ireplace(['SOAP-ENV:', 'SOAP:','soap:'], '', $result);

    $parser = simplexml_load_string($result);
    
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($parser );
die();

